# Read in-memory csv file with open() in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, xlsx

I have a dataframe. I want to write this dataframe from an excel file to a csv without saving it to disk. Looked like StringIO() was the clear solution. I then wanted to open the file like object from in memory with open() but was getting a type error. How do I get around this type error and read the in memory csv file with open()? Or, actually, is it wrong to assume the open() will work?

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StringIO
```

The error cites the row below. From the code that's even further below.

```
f = open(writer_file)
```

To get a proper example I had to open the file "pandas_example" after creation. I then removed a row, then the code runs into an empty row.

```
from pandas import util
df = util.testing.makeDataFrame()
df.to_excel('pandas_example.xlsx')
    
df_1 = pd.read_excel('pandas_example.xlsx')

writer_file = io.StringIO()
    
write_to_the_in_mem_file = csv.writer(writer_file, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
    
write_to_the_in_mem_file.writerow(df_1)
    
f = open(writer_file)

while f.readline() not in (',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n', '\n'):
        pass

final_df = pd.read_csv(f, header=None)
    

f.close()
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `open(writer_file)`? You seem to already know that `writer_file` is a [file-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), which is all a correct usage of `open` would return. Presumably you can just use `writer_file` however you were planning to use `f`.

Comment: @Brian This code would be followed by ```f.readline()``` and would accomplish readline() (obviously) and would continue to do this until a newline is found using this specifically ```while f.readline() not in (',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,\n', '\n'): pass``` and then go on to do some other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of `writer_file` as what is returned from `open()`, you don't need to open it again.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import util
import io

# Create test file
df = util.testing.makeDataFrame()
df.to_excel('pandas_example.xlsx')
    
df_1 = pd.read_excel('pandas_example.xlsx')

writer_file = io.StringIO()
df_1.to_csv(writer_file)
writer_file.seek(0)     # Rewind back to the start    

for line in writer_file:
    print(line.strip())
```

The `to_csv()` call writes the dataframe into your memory file in CSV format.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
writer_file = io.StringIO()
```

, `writer_file` is already a file-like object. It already has a `readline` method, as well as `read`, `write`, `seek`, etc. See [`io.TextIOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase), which `io.StringIO` inherits from.

In other words, `open(writer_file)` is unnecessary or, rather, it results in a type error (as you already observed).